# Android. MoPub SDK. Code snippet integration

Tags: android, mopub

I'm trying to integrate MoPub into my application but I am not sure on where exactly to place the code snippet inside the `onCreate()` method of my activity:

```
mAdView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxx"); // Enter your Ad Unit ID from www.mopub.com
mAdView.loadAd();
```

Do i place it before or after the call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` ?

Yes, I know it's a very trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your code after `setContentView` because you use findViewById for mAdView.